# Gormless LDAP with Spring Security in Grails

Tags: grails, ldap, spring-security

Here's my grails config for ldap

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'uid=admin,ou=system,dc=example,dc=com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'secret'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://localhost:1389'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase = 'ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'dc=example,dc=com'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = false

grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames=['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']
```

This is my log

```
DEBUG springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter  - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG authentication.ProviderManager  - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider  - Processing authentication request for user: rsom
DEBUG search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch  - Searching for user 'rsom', with user search [ searchFilter: '(uid={0})', searchBase: 'dc=example,dc=com', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
DEBUG support.AbstractContextSource  - Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://localhost:1389'
DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate  - Searching for entry in under DN '', base = 'dc=example,dc=com', filter = '(uid={0})'
DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate  - Found DN: uid=rsom,dc=example,dc=com
DEBUG authentication.BindAuthenticator  - Attempting to bind as uid=rsom,dc=example,dc=com
DEBUG ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource  - Removing pooling flag for user uid=rsom,dc=example,dc=com
DEBUG support.AbstractContextSource  - Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://localhost:1389'
DEBUG userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator  - Getting authorities for user uid=rsom,dc=example,dc=com
DEBUG userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator  - Searching for roles for user 'rsom', DN = 'uid=rsom,dc=example,dc=com', with filter uniquemember={0} in search base 'ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com'
DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate  - Using filter: uniquemember=uid=rsom,dc=example,dc=com
INFO  core.LdapTemplate  - The returnObjFlag of supplied SearchControls is not set but a ContextMapper is used - setting flag to true
DEBUG support.AbstractContextSource  - Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://localhost:1389'
DEBUG authentication.ProviderManager  - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - select top ? this_.id as id23_0_, this_.version as version23_0_, this_.account_expired as account3_23_0_, this_.account_locked as account4_23_0_, this_.enabled as enabled23_0_, this_.entity_id as entity6_23_0_, this_."password" as password7_23_0_, this_.password_expired as password8_23_0_, this_.username as username23_0_ from user this_ where (this_.username=?)
WARN  springsecurity.GormUserDetailsService  - User not found: rsom
DEBUG support.TransactionTemplate  - Initiating transaction rollback on application exception
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User not found
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:202)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GormUserDetailsService$_loadUserByUsername_closure1.doCall(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

What do I need to do in order to tell grails and spring-security-ldap not to look in my database for the user that is authenticated through ldap?

I'm using grails 1.3.7, Spring Security Core 1.1.2, Spring Security Ldap 1.0.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it's defaulting to the GormUserDetailsService. Try setting this configuration to false also:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.conf.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = false
```

Make sure that the following is false also. Remember me attempts to use Gorm too

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.conf.ldap.useRememberMe = false
```

I noticed the spring-security-ldap plugin's `SpringSecurityLdapGrailsPlugin.groovy` has a if/ifelse/else block which sets the userDetailsService.

For Reference:

```
        if (conf.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles) {
            ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(GrailsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator, contextSource, conf.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase) {
                groupRoleAttribute = conf.ldap.authorities.groupRoleAttribute
                groupSearchFilter = conf.ldap.authorities.groupSearchFilter
                searchSubtree = conf.ldap.authorities.searchSubtree
                if (conf.ldap.authorities.defaultRole) {
                    defaultRole = conf.ldap.authorities.defaultRole
                }
                ignorePartialResultException = conf.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException // false
                if (conf.ldap.useRememberMe && conf.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles) {
                    userDetailsService = ref('ldapRememberMeUserDetailsService')
                }
                else {
                    userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
                }
                retrieveDatabaseRoles = conf.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles // false
            }
        }
        else if (conf.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles) {
            ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(DatabaseOnlyLdapAuthoritiesPopulator) {
                if (conf.ldap.authorities.defaultRole) {
                    defaultRole = conf.ldap.authorities.defaultRole
                }
                if (conf.ldap.useRememberMe) {
                    userDetailsService = ref('ldapRememberMeUserDetailsService')
                }
                else {
                    userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(NullLdapAuthoritiesPopulator)
        }
```